# Record sound in android

Tags: android

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
startActivityForResult(intent, VoiceHandler.VOICE_FLAG);
```

This code execute fine with my ICS device but not with my android 2.3 device this code throws

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }
```

Comment: Is there any application capable of sound recording in your 2.3 device? You might want to handle that exception and warn the user that the device has no sound recording capabilities.

Comment: Yes, My device already have sound recording capabilities

Comment: And what permissions have you declared in your manifest file?

Comment: I m not setting any permission

Comment: You need to record a voice with default recorder through intent. Or, you may use by progrmatically with `MediaRecorder` class. Becuase, some version os will not support this uri. I've also tried this. Finally, i choose `MediaRecorder` Class.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**for your Manifest**

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

**to generate the Intent:**

```
i = new Intent("android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND");
```

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? Paste your logcat output, if you may.

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You declare the intent filter when your own application can handle that intent. But, clearly his application is trying to invoke another sound recording application.